# How could I select the keys py correct value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a object in below

```
{ "a": true, "b": true, "c": false, "d": true }
```

and I wanna get the array `[a,b,d]` by select the object when its value is true, I know I can use for loop to struggle to do it, but I wanna just a elegant API to help handle it, cause I an a rubist(write ruby code), there's exist the `select` API can help me, but in javascript world, it seems lack of those API, everything looks must do by yourself, that's weird.

I have study the lib `lodash`, it looks exist many good tool/API, but for now, I havn't get the function I want, maybe the reason is I'm not familiar with `lodash` lib, anyway, is anyone know how can select the keys from object values I specify in elegant API/way?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter(function(el){
return obj[el];
});`

Comment: @Rayon, it's work, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object.keys combine with filter

```js
var obj = { "a": true, "b": true, "c": false, "d": true }

var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var keys = [];
_.each( obj, function( val, key ) {
  if ( val ) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
});
```

Comment: it only pick one key not all keys in array

Comment: It maybe work, but when I use lodash in react-native environment, it seems occurs some bug, I haven't knew the real reason, but thank you, if I have solve the confusion, I will reply it.